# Electricity problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, electrostatics, free-body-diagram

•   Two small metallic spheres, each of mass 5 g, are suspended as pendulums by light strings from a common point as shown in Figure. The spheres are given the same electric charge, and it is found that they come to equilibrium when separated by 0.1m away. If each string is 25 cm long, what is the magnitude of the charge on each sphere?. Also, find the tension in the string. [image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange Physics! Homework-like questions should ask about a specific physics concept and show some effort to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. See our [meta site](//meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5958) for more guidance on how to edit your question to make it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw a free body diagram for one of the charges with three forces on it.
The required angle can be found from the geometry of the problem using the dimensions in the diagram.